# Как получить локальный ip адрес клиента?

Tags: php, laravel, ip

Хочу сделать небольшой опросник, в котором для уникальности каждого конкретного пользователя, используется его локальный ip-адрес. Сайт находится на локальном веб-сервере (OpenServer). Когда пытаюсь получить ip-адрес клиента (пользователя), всегда выводит 127.0.0.1, хотя адрес моего пк совсем другой. Я понимаю, что **Request::ip()** прекрасно заработал бы, если сайт лежал на каком-нибудь хостинге, но как быть в моем случае? Можно ли как то выделить уникальность каждого локального пользователя? Всем большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: А вам нужно идентифицировать клиента? Или просто для того что бы клиент прошел опросник один раз?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: Один пользователь, может проходить опросник сколько угодно раз. После каждого прохождения опросника, данные о пользователе удаляются. Еще раз, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] - выводит 127.0.0.1 всегда, у любого локального пользователя)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать любую из следующих двух функций.

Обе функции эквивалентны разнице только в том, как и откуда извлекаются значения.

Первый `getenv()` используется для получения значений из переменных среды `PHP`, а второй - `$ _SERVER` используется для получения значений с веб-сервера (например - `apache`).

**Вариант с использованием `getenv()`.**

```
function get_client_ip_env() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress;
}
```

**Вариант второй с использованием `$ _SERVER`.**

```
function get_client_ip_server() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress;
}
```

> Примечание. `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` иногда возвращает внутренний или локальный IP-адрес, что обычно не полезно. Кроме того, он будет возвращать список, разделенный запятыми, если он был переадресован из нескольких IP-адресов.

Comment: Благодарю, но а есть ли в Laravel стандартные методы получения локального ip?

Comment: @YuriGo С `Laravel` не так хорошо знаком. Не могу сказать. Но уверен можете добавить это как `Helper` в ваш проект. И использовать.

Comment: Сейчас попробовал, выводит ::1..

Comment: Это IPv6 ........